# How to pass non-scope variables to AngularJS filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array of pairs of amounts and currencies. The latter not just 'USD' or 'EUR', but is an object that contains formatting rules for that currency. I've written a filter for formatting the amount, but it only works if I hard code the formatting arguments:

```
// arguments: currency symbol, is symbol prefix, decimal symbol, digit group symbol
{{ entry.amount | currency24: '$',true,'.',',' } //USD example
{{ entry.amount | currency24: '€',false,'.',',' } //EUR example
```

What I'd like to be able to do is put the whole object in there like so:

```
{{entry.amount | currency24: entry.currency }} // currency object holds all the formatting parameters, but I could just as well pass them one by one
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: `entry` is not a part of $scope. It come from an ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="entry in entries"
```

That's why I'm having problems passing it to a filter.

Comment: Can you show your currency24 filter implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to pass any object to filter just like you mentioned.

HTML markup stays the same you wanted:

```
<p ng-repeat="entry in entries">
  {{entry.amount | currency24: entry.currency }}
</p>
```

And the following code does what you asked for:

```
.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.entries = [{
      amount: 35,
      currency: {
        symbol: '$'
      }
    }, {
      amount: 40,
      currency: {
        symbol: '€'
      }
    }];
})

.filter('currency24', function() {
  return function(amount, currencyObject) {
    return amount + currencyObject.symbol;
  };
});
```

And check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7M9w30k63TPliTTJ1Blc?p=preview).

Comment: Forgot to mention that entry is not in `$scope`, rather it's from an ng-repeat: `ng-repeat="entry in entries"`. `entries`, is in `$scope`, though. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: that shouldn't be the problem, i guess. i updated the answer and plunker. did i misunderstand your question?

Comment: You're correct. I found that my problem was in another part of my application which caused that the `entry.currency` object was actually undefined. Thanks a lot for your help.